# "Plugged in, not charging" after upgrade to Windows 10 from 8.1

Tags: laptop, battery, windows-10-upgrade

I have an ASUS X551MA laptop that I recently upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. It charged just fine with Windows 8.1, but ever since it upgraded to Windows 10, whenever I plug it in, it shows the status "Plugged in, not charging". I've tried all the solutions I could find, but nothing worked. It does not have a removable battery and I cannot take apart the laptop. Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: What percentage of charge is the  battery?

Comment: It is at 95% battery.

Comment: Then don't worry about it. As long as the battery will charge to 95% everything is working as it should.

Comment: I'm not necessarily worried about the percentage it's at, just that it went down while it was plugged in and shut down. It was plugged in at 100% during the upgrade process and kept going down since then even though I have not unplugged it at all. However, is there a way I can troubleshoot it and make sure it's just that Windows 10 capped it to a 95% charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely not a problem.  If the charging software finds that your laptop is plugged-in most of the time, it does not charge all the way to 100% because fully charging it supposedly reduces the life of the battery.  You may find a setting to tell it to adjust anyway, but not sure exactly where on an ASUS driver. Most likely by right clicking the battery icon and exploring the submenus.

Comment: If this was true, then wouldn't have it been full when I turned it on this morning? I had it shut off since Monday this week, when the Windows 10 upgrade finished, but instead the battery went down from 98% to 95%.

Comment: The limits on charging percentage can occur even when “powered off” - whatever that means nowadays.  Have you updated firmware and device drivers?  It may be going through recalibration.

Comment: Okay. I will update the drivers and wait about a day, and mark this answer as best if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated everything, including the drivers and BIOS, waited a day, and now it charges to 99%!